# jQuery timer to trigger events on time x, time y, time z possible?

Tags: jquery, events, timer, triggers

Currently my webapp recieves websocket data to trigger actions.

This breaks upon page reloads therefore I want a client-side solution where I be able to trigger a certain event.

Is this idea possible?

Say you have

- TimeX  = 10 seconds from current_time  should start trigger X
- TimeY  = 20 seconds from current_time  should start trigger Y
- TimeZ  = 30 seconds from current_time  should start trigger Z

  1. Would it be possible to store these inside the html and have some countdown trigger execute when the seconds have been countdown to zero?
  2. What if a browser would redirect just when between countdown 0-1 would it be possible to trigger the event still, with say a 2/3 failover time?

I have modest jQuery experience would love to hear some feedback and thoughts on this. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use `setInterval()` to set a delayed call to a function. Something like this:

```
var trigger;
function myFunc(t) {
    switch (t) {
        case "Y": 
            callTriggerY();
            trigger = "Z";
            break;
        case "Z": 
            callTriggerZ();
            trigger = "X";
            break;
        default: 
            callTriggerX();
            trigger = "Y";
            break;
}

setInterval(function() { myFunc(trigger); }, 10000); // call on interval
$(window).unload(function() { // call on leaving/reloading page
    myFunc(trigger);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To 1. :

Yes thats possible.

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $('.timer').each(function(entity) {
        setTimeout(function(eval(entity.attr("data-timer-code"))), parseInt(entity.attr("data-timeout")));
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="timer" data-timeout="12000" data-timer-code="asdf()"></div>
```

What I do there is: I add special data to a div and in the JavaScript code, I take all those divs and create Timers for each of them.

To 2. :

I sadly have no idea on how to pass that out of the pagecontext and reload the timers when the page is loaded again.